# Got "cy.click failed because the page updated while this command was executing" error

Tags: cypress

I wrote this code to click on the first option of a dropdown and ran it in Cypress

```
it('Choosing tag', () => {
    cy.get('[data-appearance="textfield"]').eq(1).click();
    cy.get('[role="option"]').eq(0).as('option').should('be.visible');
    cy.get('@option').then(($option) => {
      cy.wrap($option).click();
    });
  });
```

But on the cy.click phase I got this error

> Timed out retrying after 4050ms: cy.click() failed because the page updated while this command was executing. Cypress tried to locate elements based on this query:
>
> > <button.ng-star-inserted>
>
> We initially found matching element(s), but while waiting for them to become actionable, they disappeared from the page. Common situations why this happens:
> Your JS framework re-rendered asynchronously
> Your app code reacted to an event firing and removed the element
>
> You can typically solve this by breaking up a chain. For example, rewrite:
>
> cy.get('button').click().click()
> to
> cy.get('button').as('btn').click()
> cy.get('@btn').click()

As you can see in my code, I followed recommendations from the error text but it didn't help. When I visit the page as a user, the required element is clickable.

I hope there are ways to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just use `cy.get('[role="option"]').eq(0).click();` ?

Comment: That's what I did in the first place and got this exact error unfortunately

Comment: Can you specify the Cypress version you use? Is it pre 12?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To stop the test waiting for actionability, you can add the `{force:true}` option.

This means that you will be using the old version of the button, but that may be the quickest way around your problem.

There is no need to `then()` and `wrap()`, it does nothing.

```js
cy.get('[data-appearance="textfield"]').eq(1).click();
cy.get('[role="option"]').eq(0).as('option').should('be.visible');

cy.get('@option').click({force:true})
```

In  a real-world test you will look for

- an artifact on the page (e.g `cy.contains(some-page-text)`)
- or a network intercept (e.g `cy.intercept('some-api-response')`)

to be sure the page is stable ***before*** clicking the button.

Since there is no info about your page, I can't give you a specific answer about that.

Comment: After adding {force:true} the error has gone but I want to actually click on a dropdown option because if I can't do that the whole test has no sense. It's an Angular page. What else should I mention to help with specifying the answer? Thank you

Comment: Have launched my test today and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, **it worked after I reloaded the page where Cypress was running**. The problem was that **I opened another tab in the browser**, and then, the browser showed me the Cypress message in each test run causing my app to reload in every test. I hope you find it helpful.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzLDQ.png)